# Crontab @reboot commands not running correctly

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

Normal cron jobs (not using the `@` symbol) run just fine.

For testing purposes, I have set up a command to be run `echo "hi" > /home/kasperfred/reboot.txt` which works when running from terminal, and using running as a normal cronjob with the crontab command:

```
* * * * * echo "hi" > /home/kasperfred/reboot.txt
```

But the following command doesn't work:

```
@reboot echo "hi" > /home/kasperfred/reboot.txt
```

When using `sudo reboot` to reboot, no reboot.txt is written, however, syslog logs the command as successfully run.

From syslog:

```
Jun 11 14:30:03 zeus cron[2224]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jun 11 14:30:03 zeus cron[2224]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jun 11 14:30:03 zeus CRON[2266]: (kasperfred) CMD (echo "hi" > /home/kasperfred/reboot.txt)
```

What am I doing wrong, and if this cannot be solved, what alternatives are there for running scripts at boot time?

I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Do you have a separate home partition (or an encrypted home directory)? Have you tried writing to somewhere like `/tmp/reboot.txt` instead?

Comment: @steeldriver it seems to work when setting the directory to /tmp even with `@reboot`. However, this doesn't quite explain the initial problem; namely why it doesn't launch the jupyter notebook server when it works in terminal (the notebook-dir is not encrypted)

Comment: Well *that* sounds like a whole other question - usually the issue is either that `cron` does not provide a suitable environment, or that other services on which the program depends are not started or are not yet ready - probably the *right* way to do it is to create a `systemd` service

Comment: @KasperFredenslund you set cronjob via `crontab -e` command or you set it in `/etc/cron.d/` ?

Comment: @Bahram I did use `crontab -e`

Comment: @KasperFredenslund Please check this answer [Crontab Bugs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root) What about root user ? is it working for root ?

Comment: I can confirm this is a bug of Cron. Some task just doesn't work on `@reboot`. For example: https://askubuntu.com/a/970795/566421