# Cron job to run python script at reboot does not work

Tags: scripts, python, cron, desktop-environments, mate

I am new to linux and I read and followed many instructions to run a python script at reboot but non of them worked:

this is the command I want to run:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/am/projects/AMAcc/map.py
```

I used `crontab -e` and added

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/am/projects/AMAcc/map.py
```

I tried `sudo crontab -e` and added the same command

I even edited `/etc/crontab` file and added above command.

Tried adding `#!/usr/bin/python3` at top of my python code and changing its permissions like:
`sudo chmod a+x map.py`

As documents suggested that all users would be able to run cron jobs if `cron.deny` file exists but its empty, so I tried creating empty `cron.deny` files in both `/etc/cron.deny` and `/usr/lib/cron/cron.deny`. But still no luck running the cron job.

What am I doing worng?

Comment: What does happen instead? Do you get any error? You probably will have to add the path of the folder containing your script to the path variable within the crontab

Comment: @George yes I have tried it as i mentioned in my question.

Comment: @derHugo I don't get any errors. nothing happens as if I haven't done anything.  could you please tell me how to add it to path variable? because there is no path variables in my current crontab file

Comment: What does the script do? Is it a GUI application?

Comment: @pa4080 yes, it uses PyQt and opens a browser

Comment: You should export few environment variables, as `$DISPLAY` and `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`. Please provide your Ubuntu version and Desktop Environment. I think I can show you how to export them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start a GUI application from cron?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514167/how-to-start-a-gui-application-from-cron)

Comment: I'm using `MATE Desktop Environment 1.16.1` on a raspberry Pi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crontab and C program that should be executed into a terminal window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955582/crontab-and-c-program-that-should-be-executed-into-a-terminal-window)

Comment: Hi, AshkanMobayenKhiabani, I've updated and tested my answer. Regards!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To execute any GUI application from Cron you should export few desktop environment variables. In most cases it is quite enough to export the current `$DISPLAY` value. I would suggest you to create an additional startup (bash) script, that will launch your application.

In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/744751/566421) is provided robust approach how to find and export the current user's `$DISPLAY` value. But there is a problem. While the user is not logged into the DE the `$DISPLAY` value is not set. Sо we could add an additional condition, like it is made in [this answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/958231/566421):

```bsh
# Get the value of the $DISPLAY variable for the current user. Unset it just in case this is a `ssh -X` connection
unset DISPLAY;
while [ "$DISPLAY" == "" ]; do
        export DISPLAY=$(w "$USER" | awk 'NF > 7 && $2 ~ /tty[0-9]+/ {print $3; exit}' 2>/dev/null) && sleep 3
done
```

- This condition works in all other cases, but it fails within `@reboot` Cron jobs and I can't figure out the reason. So, within the script below is used another approach to check whether the user is logged in Mate.

Some applications need and few more variables (for example see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/955591/566421) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/911958/566421) answers) as `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and `$DESKTOP_SESSION`. In my opinion the best approach is to [find the current user's desktop session process](https://askubuntu.com/a/956739/566421) within the directory [`/proc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/proc.5.html) (process information pseudo-filesystem) and export all variables from the file `environ` that is inside `/proc/process-number`.

I've created a small project, called [cron-gui-launcher](https://github.com/pa4080/cron-gui-launcher) dedicated to this. [It works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xShzFOrZKO8) but it's not tested for all user's cases (like the current). Here I've extracted the essential part that refers to Mate DE and made the modification mentioned above.

**1.** Create an executable file with this content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -e

# Check whether the user is logged in Mate
while [ -z "$(pgrep mate-session -n -U $UID)" ]; do
        sleep 3 && count=$((count+1)) && echo "$count" > /tmp/mate-cron.log
done

# Get the content of the Current-Desktop-Session Environment File as an array:
EnvVarList=`cat -e "/proc/$(pgrep mate-session -n -U $UID)/environ" | sed 's/\^@/\n/g'`

# Export the Current-Desktop-Session Environment Variables:
for EnvVar in $EnvVarList; do
        echo "$EnvVar" >> /tmp/mate-cron.log
        export "$EnvVar"
done

# Execute the list of the input commands
nohup "${1}" >/dev/null 2>&1 &

exit 0
```

- **Better version of the scrip: [How can I show notify-send messages triggered by crontab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978382/how-can-i-show-notify-send-messages-triggered-by-crontab)**

**2.** Now in `crontab` use:

```
@reboot /path-to-the/script "your-application"
```

**3.** Notes:

- This script shall not work with root's `crontab`. Because of the variables `$UID` and `$USER`. You could replace them wit the certain user's UID and NAME.
- For other DE change `mate-session` from this part `$(pgrep mate-session -n -U $UID)` with the name of the process of the other DE, for example `gnome-session`.
- Maybe **for GUI applications, that are executed within system startup it is better idea to create an entry within Startup Applications**. For Mate DE: `Control Centre > Personal > Startup Applications` ([source](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/run-application-on-startup/5222/3)).

**4.** Here is presented how the script works:

[image]