# How can I get cron to run my Python script?

Tags: bash, python, cron

I made a little script that asks Yobit about bitcoin concurrency, and sends some notifications in Ubuntu 17. It works fine if I run the command `python coinrates.py`. I have made it executable and put `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top of the file, but it won't work automatically through `cron`.

I tried:

```
* * * * * ~/test/yobit/checker.py
```

and

```
* * * * * python ~/test/yobit/checker.py
```

But it doesn't work.

Here is my syslog

```
Dec  2 12:01:00 plombir-N53SV systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec  2 12:01:00 plombir-N53SV anacron[1303]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2017-12-02
Dec  2 12:01:00 plombir-N53SV anacron[1303]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec  2 12:17:01 plombir-N53SV CRON[1888]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  2 13:01:04 plombir-N53SV systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec  2 13:01:04 plombir-N53SV anacron[3601]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2017-12-02
Dec  2 13:01:04 plombir-N53SV anacron[3601]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec  2 13:17:01 plombir-N53SV CRON[3997]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  2 14:00:38 plombir-N53SV systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec  2 14:00:38 plombir-N53SV anacron[5171]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2017-12-02
Dec  2 14:00:38 plombir-N53SV anacron[5171]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec  2 14:17:01 plombir-N53SV CRON[5846]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  2 15:04:01 plombir-N53SV systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec  2 15:04:01 plombir-N53SV anacron[7072]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2017-12-02
Dec  2 15:04:01 plombir-N53SV anacron[7072]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec  2 15:17:01 plombir-N53SV CRON[7374]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  2 16:01:41 plombir-N53SV systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec  2 16:01:41 plombir-N53SV anacron[8489]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2017-12-02
Dec  2 16:01:41 plombir-N53SV anacron[8489]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec  2 16:17:01 plombir-N53SV CRON[8881]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  2 17:04:01 plombir-N53SV systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec  2 17:04:01 plombir-N53SV anacron[10177]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2017-12-02
Dec  2 17:04:01 plombir-N53SV anacron[10177]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec  2 17:17:01 plombir-N53SV CRON[10489]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  2 18:01:03 plombir-N53SV systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec  2 18:01:03 plombir-N53SV anacron[11610]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2017-12-02
Dec  2 18:01:03 plombir-N53SV anacron[11610]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec  2 18:17:01 plombir-N53SV CRON[12238]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  2 19:01:15 plombir-N53SV systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec  2 19:01:15 plombir-N53SV anacron[13850]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2017-12-02
Dec  2 19:01:15 plombir-N53SV anacron[13850]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec  2 19:10:57 plombir-N53SV crontab[14200]: (plombir) BEGIN EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 19:11:19 plombir-N53SV crontab[14200]: (plombir) REPLACE (plombir)
Dec  2 19:11:19 plombir-N53SV crontab[14200]: (plombir) END EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 19:12:01 plombir-N53SV cron[770]: (plombir) RELOAD (crontabs/plombir)
Dec  2 19:17:01 plombir-N53SV CRON[14450]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  2 19:19:01 plombir-N53SV CRON[14641]: (root) CMD (   test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond)
Dec  2 19:26:45 plombir-N53SV crontab[14932]: (plombir) BEGIN EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 19:27:00 plombir-N53SV crontab[14932]: (plombir) END EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 19:27:02 plombir-N53SV crontab[14950]: (plombir) BEGIN EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 19:28:52 plombir-N53SV crontab[14950]: (plombir) REPLACE (plombir)
Dec  2 19:28:52 plombir-N53SV crontab[14950]: (plombir) END EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 19:28:59 plombir-N53SV crontab[15043]: (plombir) LIST (plombir)
Dec  2 19:29:01 plombir-N53SV cron[770]: (plombir) RELOAD (crontabs/plombir)
Dec  2 19:45:29 plombir-N53SV crontab[15654]: (plombir) LIST (plombir)
Dec  2 19:56:06 plombir-N53SV crontab[16106]: (plombir) BEGIN EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 19:56:28 plombir-N53SV crontab[16120]: (plombir) BEGIN EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 19:56:50 plombir-N53SV crontab[16120]: (plombir) REPLACE (plombir)
Dec  2 19:56:50 plombir-N53SV crontab[16120]: (plombir) END EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 19:57:01 plombir-N53SV cron[770]: (plombir) RELOAD (crontabs/plombir)
Dec  2 19:59:07 plombir-N53SV crontab[16250]: (plombir) BEGIN EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 19:59:48 plombir-N53SV crontab[16250]: (plombir) REPLACE (plombir)
Dec  2 19:59:48 plombir-N53SV crontab[16250]: (plombir) END EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 20:00:01 plombir-N53SV cron[770]: (plombir) RELOAD (crontabs/plombir)
Dec  2 20:00:19 plombir-N53SV crontab[16278]: (plombir) BEGIN EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 20:04:38 plombir-N53SV systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec  2 20:04:38 plombir-N53SV anacron[16445]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2017-12-02
Dec  2 20:04:38 plombir-N53SV anacron[16445]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec  2 20:08:25 plombir-N53SV crontab[16598]: (plombir) LIST (plombir)
Dec  2 20:17:01 plombir-N53SV CRON[16931]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  2 20:28:20 plombir-N53SV crontab[17378]: (plombir) BEGIN EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 20:29:11 plombir-N53SV crontab[17378]: (plombir) REPLACE (plombir)
Dec  2 20:29:11 plombir-N53SV crontab[17378]: (plombir) END EDIT (plombir)
Dec  2 20:30:01 plombir-N53SV cron[770]: (plombir) RELOAD (crontabs/plombir)
Dec  2 20:32:19 plombir-N53SV crontab[18553]: (plombir) LIST (plombir)
Dec  2 20:37:00 plombir-N53SV crontab[19748]: (plombir) LIST (plombir)
Dec  2 20:37:17 plombir-N53SV crontab[19765]: (plombir) LIST (plombir)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron job to run python script at reboot does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970771/cron-job-to-run-python-script-at-reboot-does-not-work) also [How can I show notify-send messages triggered by crontab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978382/how-can-i-show-notify-send-messages-triggered-by-crontab)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the **full path** to your python bin file. 
At the command line type:

```
whereis python
```

You should see something along the lines of: `/usr/bin/python` and perhaps a few others. Use that **full path** in your cron file, so example:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python ~/test/yobit/checker.py
```

Then also use the full path to your home directory:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/USERNAME/test/yobit/checker.py
```

Comment: I tried, does not work.., I just started to learn Cron, may be I save it wrong? But if I open it again - my code is there, and I tested it echoing some text in the other file, it works well.

Comment: Ok, take a look at your **syslog** file to see what cron is complaining about and paste it here. The log file is located at `/var/log/syslog` you can use the tail or cat command to view the file, if you need to filter then do so for **cron** as follows: `cat /var/log/syslog |grep cron`

Comment: I did, hope it's big enough. It's actually bigger, I just copied a chunk.

Comment: You tried editing my answer to paste your update, you should edit your question to paste your updates :) I did see the log file that you pasted though but there was nothing about your cron file. Can you paste the results of `cat /var/log/syslog |grep checker` and tell me what users crontab you  are editing? Is it the root user or is it your own user?

Comment: Sorry, I did what you ask.

Comment: Thanks, but now change the command slightly and filter for **checker** as follows: `cat /var/log/syslog |grep checker` then paste the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69615/discussion-between-kingmilo-and-yahya).

Comment: The full path is not the issue with notifications. The issue is that cron has no idea about user's session bus. It is better to not run these types of things as cron jobs, but instead to run them as a background service in the user session. You also really do not want to run as often as is done in the crontab here, as it will almost certainly mean the script constantly keeps getting run over and over again, with no interim timeout.