# minimize skype after autostart

Tags: cron, skype, autostart, minimize

"Launch skype in the background" is not an option now so I'm trying to bypass it. I tried to add this line to the autostart file:

`&& sleep 5 && xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class Skype)`

but this command opens skype as an empty window and I dunno why.

I tried to make a cron:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class Skype)
```

It doesn't work as well and I dunno why.

Can you tell me why these options doesn't work for me and how to make them behave itself? :D

Tnank you!

Comment: Please read: [How can I show notify-send messages triggered by crontab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978382/how-can-i-show-notify-send-messages-triggered-by-crontab/978413#978413) and [Cron job to run python script at reboot does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970771/cron-job-to-run-python-script-at-reboot-does-not-work/970795#970795)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to 17.10 and switched from Unity to Gnome. It fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an XY problem. Newer versions of Skype does support starting in the background. Go to *Tools* > *Settings* and toggle on "*Launch Skype in the background*".

[image]

Comment: I have the latest version and it produces unclosable window if this option selected.

Comment: Strange! Works fine here, Skype v8.15.0.4 on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Same version, but Ubuntu 16.04. I googled this problem and I'm not the only one who faced it. Good opportunity to learn shell scripting:D